# Have request parameters still validity during a page reload dued to f:ajax with render="@all"

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I use the same page for three types of users and the title depends the link I choose: User1 can see link1, user2 can see link1 and link2 and user3 can see link1, link2 and link3.

In the link is specified a request parameter which defines the page title:

> menu enrty1:
>   http://x.y.com/.../subscriptionListView.xhtml?**listViewName=myParamForPageTitle1**
>   menu entry2: http://x.y.com/.../subscriptionListView.xhtml?**listViewName=myParamForPageTitle2**
>   menu entry3: http://x.y.com/.../subscriptionListView.xhtml?**listViewName=myParamForPageTitle3**

Then in the page I have a `<c:if test` for setting the title:

```
<ui:composition
   ...
   <ui:define name="metadata">
    <c:if test="#{subscriptionListController.model.listViewName eq 'mySubscriptions'}">
        <ui:param name="title" value="#{msg.subscriptionTitleMySubscriptions}"/>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="#{subscriptionListController.model.listViewName eq 'paidSubscriptions'}">
        <ui:param name="title" value="#{msg.subscriptionTitlePaidSubscriptions}"/>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="#{subscriptionListController.model.listViewName eq 'allSubscriptions'}">
        <ui:param name="title" value="#{msg.subscriptionTitleAllSubscriptions}"/>
    </c:if>

    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="listViewName" value="#{subscriptionListController.model.listViewName}"/>
        ...
```

In the corresponding bean the `listViewName` default value ist set to `myParamForPageTitle1`

The concerning page has a list of subscriptions and for every entry there is a related checkbox.
When I check a subscription, all the other subscriptions' checkboxes related to the same user must be disabled/enabled.

I do this using f:ajax event:

```
<td>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="personalNumber"
        class="cb"
        value="#{listRow.rowData.personalNumber}"
        disabled="#{logic to disable/enable}" >

        <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="@all" listener="#{listController.setPersonalNumber(listRow.rowData.dbId)}"/>                  
    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
</td>
```

The problem is that when I load the page from link3 and check a checkbox and the page is reloaded due to the *render="@all"*, the title changes to the default one.

Have the f:viewParam still some effect resp. are the request parameters passed again with a *render="@all"*

Comment: What's your backing bean scope? Also realize that there's probably a cleaner way to do some of what you're doing here. Not to mention the fact that you're passing a critical piece of information via an obvious URL parameter. What's your plan to handle mischievous manipulation of that `listViewName`?

Comment: @kolossus actually the scope is ViewScoped. I know there would be cleaner ways to do this, but this is a workaround for not to re-implement the application. Internally there are other checks to avoid the misuse of the parameter.